# Guardar campos de la tabla seleccionada por checkbox en Mysql realizada en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes soy nuevo nuevo en el foro, ayudenme con un problema que tengo, yo quiero guardar las filas de la tabla que ha sido seleccionada por checkbox en Mysql realizada en PHP, necesito guardar el id del producto, y la cantidad en mi base de datos Mysql eh intentado de varias formas pero no logro hacerlo, si me guarda el o los id del producto (id_prod_serv) pero no me guarda bien la cantidad o cantidades de esos productos, me guarda las cantidades pero no en el orden correcto, si escojo todos los productos si me guarda bien, pero si no estan en orden no se guarda correctamente. Este es mi codigo:
Este es mi SELECT

```html
<?php
        $query = "select B.id_paquete,A.id_prod_serv,A.nombre,B.precio_unitario FROM tb_productos_servicios A JOIN tb_paquetes B ON A.id_prod_serv = B.id_prod_serv JOIN tb_categorias C ON B.id_categoria=C.id_categoria where B.id_categoria=1";
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $query3 = "Select * from tb_eventos";
        $res3 = mysqli_query($con, $query3);
?>
```

La Tabla:

```html
<table class="table" id="tb1" table-bordered>
  <thead>
    <tr class="warning">
      <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="marcar(this);" /></th>
      <th>Productos</th>
      <th>Precio por unidad</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio por producto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <?php while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
      $id = $row2['id_paquete'];
      $nom = $row2[2];
      $pre = $row2[3];
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td class='col-xs-1'><input type="checkbox" name="idproduc[]" value="<?php echo $row2['id_prod_serv']; ?>"></td>
          <td class='col-xs-2'>
            <?php echo $nom; ?>
          </td>
          <td class='col-xs-1'>
            <div class="pull-right"><input type="number" name="val1" class="form-control monto input" style="text-align:right" value="<?php echo $pre; ?>" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class='col-xs-1'>
            <div class="pull-right"><input type="text" id="val2" name="valu[]" class="form-control monto input" style="text-align:right" value="" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class='col-xs-1'>
            <div class="pull-right"><input type="number" class="form-control monto total" value="0" readonly/>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <?php } ?>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            Total
          </td>
          <td class='col-xs-1'>
            <div class="pull-right"><input type="number" class="form-control monto totales" value="0" disabled>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Este es mi insert:

```html
<?php

require_once("conexion.php");
require_once("db.php");
if (isset($_POST['enviar_per'])) {
    //Si las variables existen (isset) y estan llenos(!empty)
    if (isset($_POST['val']) && !empty($_POST['val']) && isset($_POST['fecha']) && !empty($_POST['fecha']) && isset($_POST['horas_per']) && !empty($_POST['horas_per']) && isset($_POST['cant']) && !empty($_POST['cant']) && isset($_POST['ci']) && !empty($_POST['ci']) && isset($_POST['nom']) && !empty($_POST['nom']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['telef']) && !empty($_POST['telef']) && isset($_POST['direc']) && !empty($_POST['direc'])) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tb_cotizacion_cabecera (id_evento,fecha_registro,fecha_evento,hora,cant_personas,cedula_cliente,nombre,email,telefono,direccion,estado) VALUES ('$_POST[val]',NOW(),'$_POST[fecha]','$_POST[horas_per]','$_POST[cant]','$_POST[ci]','$_POST[nom]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[telef]','$_POST[direc]','activo')");
        $primero = $_POST['idproduc'];
        $segundo = $_POST['valu'];
        $conx = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) or die("imposible conectarse: " . mysqli_error($conx));
        mysqli_select_db($conx, $DB_NAME)or die("Problemas al conectar la bd");
        foreach ($primero as $k => $v) {
            $obtener_segundo = $segundo[$k];
                $sql = mysqli_query($conx, "INSERT INTO tb_cotizacion_detalle (id_cotizacion,id_prod_serv,cantidad) VALUES ($con->insert_id,'$v','$obtener_segundo')") or die(mysqli_error($conx));          
        }
        echo '<p style="color:green; background: #ECEFF0; margin-left:100px;">Datos guardados correctamentes</p>';
        mysqli_close($con);
        mysqli_close($conx);
    } else {
        echo '<p style="color:red; margin-left:100px; background: #ECEFF0">No se guardaron sus datos</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: al margen de tu respuesta te comento tu código es sensible a SQL INJECTION deberías usar sentencias preparadas, además de indicar el tipo de dato que esperas recibir aprovechando que usas mysqli

Comment: Gracias por decirme

Comment: No entiendo bien ni el planteamiento de la pregunta ni el código del `INSERT`, por ejemplo, ¿podrías explicar por qué haces esto: `foreach ($primero as $k => $v) {  $obtener_segundo = $segundo[$k];  ...`? Mientras más claro seas en el planteamiento recibirás una mejor ayuda. Una vez resuelto el problema que te ha llevado a plantear la pregunta, sería bueno que consideres evitar los riesgos de Inyección SQL que te comentaron más arriba. Otra cosa que veo extraña es por qué conectas de nuevo a la base de datos en medio del código,  ¿usas dos BD diferentes?

Comment: Si eso pretendo hacer primero solucionar este problema y despues evitar la inyeccion sql, uso una sola Base de Datos, y hago otra conexion, porque que necesito obtener obtener el id (id_cotizacion) del usuario que se registra en la tabla tb_cabecera_cotizacion

Comment: Hago ese foreach ($primero as $k => $v) { $obtener_segundo = $segundo[$k];  porque necesito recorrer esos dos arreglos al mismo tiempo idproduc y valu, donde idproduc es el id de los productos que voy a guardar en la tabla tb_cotizacion_detalle y valu es el arreglo de la cantidad de los productos que ingreso por fila